# Python - string replacement, re.match and re.sub in a single operation (replace a char if at end of a string)

Tags: python, regex

I have a script where I need to replace some chars that could generate some troubles with others.

I would like to optimize the number of operation required:

```
# Replace % at end of string
find_char = re.match( r'.+\%[a-zA-Z0-9]+', line)
if find_char:
    line=re.sub(r'\%','PCT',line)
```

Here I want to replace `%` but only if it is present at the end of a string, can I do this in one single operation with `re.sub`?

Comment: At the end of any word in the line

Comment: did you want to replace `%` in this string `% foo % %`?

Comment: Your accepted answer only changes if it is at the very end of the string, not any word in the string, in that case you don't need re. `str.endswith` will do the same

Comment: Just % as this is explained in comment line
Using $ is the answer

Comment: @Padraic: Ok, I see, thanks a lot for pointing this out
@ Avinash: Thanks you for having updated your answer according to these comments

Comment: I'll be running a couple of tests and will revert, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this. It replaces the `%` symbol present at the end of a string with `PCT`

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?<=\S)%(?= |$)', r'PCT', 'foo%bar foo% bar%')
>>> m
'foo%bar fooPCT barPCT'
```

If you want to replace a single `%` symbol also which was preceded by a space and followed by a space then try this,

```
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?<=[\S\s])%(?= |$)', r'PCT', 'foo%bar % foo% bar%')
>>> m
'foo%bar PCT fooPCT barPCT'
```

OR

```
>>> import regex
>>> m = regex.sub(r'(?<=^|[\S\s])%(?= |$)', r'PCT', '% foo%bar % foo% bar%')
>>> m
'PCT foo%bar PCT fooPCT barPCT'
```

Comment: Thank you, the update of your answer responds to my needs :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course, just specify that the match should be at the end of the string, using `$`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("%$", "o", "fo%")
'foo'
>>> re.sub("%$", "o", "f%o")
'f%o'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 find_char = re.match( r'.+\%[a-zA-Z0-9]+', line)
        if find_char:
            line=re.sub(r'\%$','PCT',line)
```

use $ to match a character at the end

Comment: Thanks, using $ is indeed the answer :)